# NSTimer daily triggered in a concrete hour

Tags: ios, objective-c, triggers, nstimer

I would like to execute a function every day at 23:59, so from what I have read I think I need to use a `NSTimer`.

Is there any way to can trigger an `NSTimer` at a specific time, instead of using intervals?

Comment: What platform? Will the app even be running at that time?

Comment: I need it for iOS. The app will be in background

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a timer, at least not without cheating.

If you want to alert the user to something, use `UILocalNotification`.

If you want to run since code and then alert the user, and you only care about iOS 7, use a push notification with fetch.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't want to alert the user, just execute a function for the app's manteinance at a concrete hour

Comment: Is the user interested in you trying to do that in the background??

Comment: Then it should be done when they open the app, or just before they open it (iOS background tech)...